# Marklogic Autocomplete feature

Tags: full-text-search, xquery, marklogic

I am going by [Marklogic Tutorial for Oscars](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/intro#id_21750) to develop an application for my documents that I have ingested in the database.
What I am not able to understand is that though the Search box performs autocomplete, but it doesnot do that for elements..i.e if I type Cha...then it should start suggesting all names starting with Cha..sucha as Charles, Charley etc.[image: Sample Oscars Application]

As shown in figure: I can write Decade(which will get autocompleted..) and select one among 1920s..1930s..etc.
But I dont want to specify Field name as such.I just want to type actor name and it should provide auto suggest on that...

I have looked for it in the documentation where it says that **search:suggest** function can do this; but I am new to xquery etc and dont know how to proceed...

Do I need to modify this function or add something to it?How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter a **full-text** search term, then autocomplete works on words and phrases from the **full-text** index. If you prepend a search field keyword, then the autocomplete limits to that.

I don't know the search field keywords by name, but I'd guess they are award:, decade: and winners:. So, if you type in decade:, then autocomplete should come up with decades only.

--edit--

Based on your comment, it sounds you want to change the source for autocomplete if you don't specify a specific search field. That is very easy. If you start the wizard to create an **Oscar Example application**, that option is on the first screen. You can also revisit that same wizard from the **Application Builder** after creation to apply changes.

Just open that wizard, go to the Search step, and look for a button '**Advanced Settings**'. In the middle of the overlay screen there should be a caption called '**Suggestions**', and below a drop-down to specify the Default Source, which is the source for autocompletion when you don't prefix your search term. Change that to 'name' if you want unprefixed terms to autocomplete against actor names..

HTH!

Comment: I have tried searching on award, decade etc. What it does is that first i have to type Decade(autopopulates..), then on selecting this 120s,1930s etc are suggested..and on selection of any of them, the result is obtained.But I dont want to specify the 'Decade' or any term. eg- I just want to write first name of actors..and it should auto complete with the possible suggestions...!!!

Comment: yes, that helped.Is it possible to have more than one field as default source;since i have fields as firstname, last name. Do i need to make changes in my source by adding a custom filed that contains both firstname and last name and use that as default field (as we do in other indexers such as Solr/Elasticsearch) or is there some other way round too?Further, i dont understand the usage of constraints other than Range Constraint.Marklogic tutorial doesnt seem to help much..

Comment: In reference to your comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292707/how-to-build-a-simple-search-application-in-marklogic/10293107#10293107), instead of user having to provide fullterms such as 'firstname:abc' and 'lastname:ghy', a user would rather prefer abc ghy. This is what i am trying to say in my prev comment.

Comment: @shrey: Well technically, functions like [`cts:element-values`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-values) lie behind such functionality. These accept multiple elements to be included, to take use of multiple indexes. But the search:search library as yet doesn't really utilize this possibility. You can however define a Field index. That allows including/excluding contents of specific elements. You could use that next to other indexes. Use a Field Range index on top of it to match exact values..