# How to connect html page to Marklogic Database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, marklogic, nosql

I am newbie to web designing. Here I am trying to develop a web page where it prompts for username and password and when I click on button, this html has to make connection with these username and password values entered by user to Marklogic database . Could anyone please help how to do this? Is it through Javascript or PHP? If so please advise where can I find step by step explanation of this process ? Also it is okay if I get procedure for any NOSQL database.

Comment: check this reference url  http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/whats-new/nodejs-client-api/

Comment: you can use node.js to connect to database and deal with it. Check this link as well for reference https://developer.marklogic.com/features/node-client-api

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Mit.agile for reference. I have already found them but could not able to proceed with my development.

Comment: Hi Epodax , thank you .. I have developed html file . Here I want to make connection to Marklogic database. Could you please advise how can I proceed further?

Comment: You might find some useful hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292707/how-to-build-a-simple-search-application-in-marklogic/10293107#10293107. Slush-marklogic-node in particular provides an entire search app with login out of the box.

Comment: Thank you grtjn.. I have seen it and in the documentation , it was mentioned to use node.js api client.. Could you please tell me how can I use this api in basic html file which was written in just a notepad++?

Answer (score 3):

OK. Your statement is a bit big and broad..  I decided to extract the most relevant concepts:

- Sample Application including authentication
- MarkLogic
- Javascript or PHP

Therefore, I suggest looking at a reference framework using all javascript:

http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/whats-new/samplestack/

This can have a node.js middle tier in node.js and does not require java.

It is a big  step forward and (sort of) complex, but it is a **complete example**.

If it is too much for what you are looking for, then I suggest you research more specifically what you need in these two specific items in MarkLogic documents:
HTTP Server (where you can run your HTML/CSS/Javascript from)
REST API (for which you can use against your js code)
This is a 2-tier approach where your application(HTTP) server is serving both your HTTP site as well s the default REST enpoints.